# Sequence learning with discrete/categorical output available to the objective function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Please bear with, I am still quite new to deep learning so what I am looking for may or may not make a lot of sense. But this is why I ask, I need some guidance on where to find a guiding example or paper.

Here is what I want and have:

- I am interested in sequence data (time-series actually) hence I am using RNN/LSTM/GRU and those types of things
- Now suppose I have a 1-D time-series, lets call it `X = [x_1,...,x_n]`
- For my particular problem, it turns out that `X` is a function of another function, a generator function if you will s.t. `X = f(a,b)`
- That function takes two integer parameters `a` and `b`
- Here is my problem: I want to find the value of `a` and `b` that *best* reconstructs my time-series `X` (assume that I can generate time-series with `f(a,b)`)
- This leads me to believe that I must feature the actual values of the network output, i.e. `a` and `b` in my objective function
- My objective function could be something like `objectiveFunction(X_true,X_pred)` but then my `X_pred` is generated from `f` with parameters `a` and `b`
- Further, the batch size may need to be the whole time-series (they are small, and I have many examples) but we can use big mini batches if needs be.

Suppose the search space over `a` and `b` is `[0,10]` for both (again `a` and `b` can only assume integer values). Then I have 100 pairs e.g. (6,7) for values of `a` and `b`. As I train the network I expect the weight of edge leading from the `Dense` to the categorical outputs (i.e. my parameters pairs `(a,b)`), to get maximised as the network finds better and better time-series generator parameters `a` and `b`.

Initially, I was just going to test a network structure as such:

`Input -->> RNN -->> Dense -->> Categorical output`

I want to keep it simple for now and not try anything fancier such as an LSTM as my time-series only have short-term dependencies.

Hence, any advice would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll get better response on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm not really understanding what your output must be. You're doing timeseries, so I thought you wanted it to be `{in: Xt, out: Xt+1}`. Why do you need `a` and `b`? If you do need `a` and `b`, why not train your network like `{in: Xt, out: [Xt+1, a, b]}`

Comment: @ThomasW thanks for your answer. Well precisely, I am wondering how to do this. Basically I know that my signal `X` is generated from model `f(a,b)` so really it is about fitting `f` to my data, and that involves finding parameters `a` and `b` and I need to find these through an optimisation, but this optimisation's (SGD) loss function presumably need to feature these outputs in the loss function itself? The problem is of course that these parameters are discrete (I think that is a problem at least).

Comment: On the other if I can force the model to have high edge weights which lead to `(a,b)_max` (i.e. the pair that maximise the objective) then if I can pick that edge in some robust way, then that would be great too. This way I don't need to feature them in the loss function.